# Create a string conditional, by inserting in different position if a condition

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a string conditional, by inserting in different position if a condition.

Pseudo Example:

```
is_active=True
is_ready=True

    str = 'aquire {} lorem ipsum {} another {} lorem2 {}'.format((if is_active:'activated' else ''), (if is_ready:'ready' else ''), (if is_active:'activated occurred' else ''), (if is_ready:'set to go' else ''))
```

In reality are up to 7 variables, so I try to avoid using a lot of ifs.

Result:

```
'aquire activated lorem ipsum ready another activated occurred lorem2 set to go'
```

Comment: Calculate the values of variables using if else statements before formatting them into the final string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the rule in a function:

```
def pattern(active,ready):
        rule=[ (active,'activated',''),(ready,'ready',''),(active,'activated occurred',''),(ready,'set to go','') ]
        return [ t[1] if t[0] else t[2] for t in rule ]

str= 'aquire {} lorem ipsum {} another {} lorem2 {}'
print( str.format(*pattern(True,True)) )

Out: "aquire activated lorem ipsum ready another activated occurred lorem2 set to go"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a mapper function and a dictionary that holds what to print based on position and truthy-value:

```
is_active=True
is_ready=True

d ={ (0,True)  : "activated",
     (1,True)  : "ready",
     (2,True)  : "activated occured",
     (3,True)  : "set to go",
     (4,False) : "enough said"
   }

# use a better name - gt for shortness here so line does not need to break
def gt(pos, value): 
    # if not in dict, default to empty string
    return d.get((pos,value),"")

t = 'aquire {} lorem ipsum {} another {} lorem2 {}'

# str is a built in - dont name variables like that
text = t.format(gt(0,is_active), gt(1,is_ready), gt(2,is_active), gt(3,is_ready))
print(text)

is_active=False
text = t.format(gt(0,is_active), gt(1,is_ready), gt(2,is_active), gt(3,is_ready))
print(text)
print(gt(99,False))
print(gt(4,False))
```

Output:

```
# True,True
aquire activated lorem ipsum ready another activated occured lorem2 set to go
# False,True
aquire  lorem ipsum ready another  lorem2 set to go
# gt(99,False) which is not in dict

# gt(4,False)
enough said
```

Doku: [dict.get(key[, defaultvalue])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)